# jQuery Focus / Blur for each input with same class - having issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

fiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/44zAy/11/

Everything is working as I want however, if you click inside the first input and then go to click inside the second, the first one closes and same if you click the x button.

What I need is for it to stay open even if i click inside another and only close if I blur out of it and not by doing a focus on another input. is that possible?

CODE:

```
var inputWdith = '185px';
var inputWdithReturn = '68px';

jQuery('.resize-close').hide();

jQuery(".resize-input").on('focus', function() {
 jQuery(this).animate({
  width: inputWdith
 },400);
 jQuery(this).promise().done(function(){
  jQuery(this).next('.resize-close').show();
 });
}).bind('blur', function() {
 jQuery(this).animate({
  width: inputWdithReturn
 },500);
 jQuery(this).next('.resize-close').hide(); 
});

jQuery('.resize-close').click(function(){
  jQuery(this).prev('.resize-input').animate({
  width: inputWdithReturn
 },500);; 
});
```

Comment: why not do something like:  _ALL_INPUTS.not(SELECT_CLASSES).on("focus", function(){shrink($(this));});

Comment: where shrink does the resize-close or hide() function call

Comment: I dont understand your responses guys, sorry.... :(

Answer (score 0):

For a quick fix of your current code, use the event.relatedTarget: http://jsfiddle.net/QKVL9/

The problem is that when you click into the second input, the 'blur' event is fired for the first input. So the quick fix is to check whether there is `event.relatedTarget != null`. If there is a relatedTarget, then stop execution of the 'blur' event for the first input.

But I recommend a complete refactor of this code :)

Comment: Thanks for the update, seems though it still does the same thing in your example and i would refactor  but unsure how and on a tight deadline for this lol